# Strings containing non-ASCII characters are truncated by PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a page that has a translation function [here](http://ichtyo.mnhn.fr/projects/spemuse/spemuse_page1.php). My problem here is that, when I translate the language into French, the words are cut because the page didn't interpret the words correctly. I checked posts related to my problem but none of them work.

In my page, I put these stuffs:

- `header ('Content-Type:text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1252');` -> This is just to insist the encoding on start up. I think this one is optional but I still use it.
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">`
- Equivalent translations are fetched from a database tablename: **labels**. **Labels**'s table type is InnoDB with **utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode** as default Character set.

Characters after **é** are being cut. Is there anything that I need to do to display the characters correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use UTF-8 throughout your application instead of constantly converting between legacy encodings and Unicode?

Comment: What does it mean *characters **after** é are cut*?

Comment: Do you call any string manipulation functions, between reading from database and giving out to HTML? Maybe you use one of PHP's string functions, that are not aware of unicode (e.g. `strlen` instead of `mb_strlen`).

Comment: For example I will translate **Reference** to French, the equivalent should be **Référence** but the page only display **R**.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - Actually I didn't use any string function to display the translation, what I did is just a simple **echo $row['French']**

Comment: But I don't see the problem on the linked page, and I can't understand what your application is supposed to do

Comment: @Raffaele - What do you mean by linking the page? I have provided the link of my sample page on my question.

Comment: @Raffaele - Try to change the language on the upper right of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any point in using Unicode on the backend and a code page in the frontend of a multilingual application. You either use the same encoding throughout your project, or you manually convert back and forth between `UTF-8` and `windows-1252`.

I don't think you have a problem with reading. The labels come truncated from the DB, otherwise your browser would display garbage characters. So this is not an issue with PHP/HTML, but with MySQL. In the case of `èéàòì` and the like, MySQL is certainly able to convert from UTF-8 to CP1252 (latin1). However, if this were not the case (as if we try to convert the same string from UTF-8 to CP1251), MySQL would show a question mark `?`.

In your case I think it's an input problem, ie the labels are truncated in the DB. How is this possible? You may have a UTF8 PHP and MySQL, but your browser sends `windows-1252` strings when it submits a form from a page loaded with such a charset. In your PHP script you should transcode this string to `UTF-8` **before** inserting it in the db, or connect to MySQL with `SET NAMES 'CP1252'`. Since you don't do so, you end up trying to insert a bunch of invalid UTF-8 bytes, so MySQL truncates the string and your labels are empty. Attached is a test case. Here is the `test` table

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the PHP part. Note that this script is UTF-8 encoded, so every literal string appearing in it has the same encoding.

```php
// This is a UTF-8 file, so my editor uses UTF-8 and thus each literal
// string is a UTF-8 string, since PHP only has binary strings.
$label = "Référence";

// Now let's translate this string as if it came from a browser submitting
// a form loaded from a cp1252 encoded page
$src = mb_convert_encoding($label, "CP1252", "UTF-8");

// But connect as if I were UTF-8
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8',
    'test', 'test');

// Insert the string
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ( ? )');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $src);
$stmt->execute();

// Read it
header("content-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252");
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM test') as $row)
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
```

How do you recover? Either you connect to MySQL with the `cp1252` charset and let MySQL translate for you, or you transcode the string in your script.

After correctly getting data in, you'll have to extract them and put it on a HTML page. This time you'll have the same problem, but reversed: showing a UTF-8 string in a CP1252 document. The bytes in the DB are unsuitable, because UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding, whilst in CP1252 a char is exactly 1 byte long. If you put these bytes directly into the page, the browser will show some random gibberish for the extra bytes. So, again, you either connect to the db specifying the `CP1252` charset so that MySQL takes care of the conversion and give you the right bytes, or you transcode the bytes yourself on the PHP side.

Or you'd better doing yourself a favor: use the same encoding everywhere. I suggest `UTF-8` because today is the *right thing* to do, but you can successfully opt for `CP1252` because it can represents English and French chars (and saves some storage, but I don't consider this an issue)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion  is to use the same encoding through the whole process. Use UTF-8 as the charset both in header and the meta tag.

Comment: It still doesn't really explain why parts are missing. This cannot happen just due to the page encoding.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the header and the meta tag value to

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

And still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that your data is not stored correctly in the database. If you are working with mysqli you can try to set the charset of the connection object, before reading or writing to the database.

```
// tells the mysqli connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

For other databases see [UTF-8 for PHP and MySQL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8). Maybe it's necessary to insert the french textes again (with this setting), because the existing textes could be invalid now.

Your linked example page is correctly encoded with UTF-8 (the file format), though your meta tag is a bit incorrect:

```
<!meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

The `<!` is not a commented out, you would have to write `<!--` instead. The best would be to declare it only once for UTF-8 and remove other meta tags.

Comment: This seems a *stolen answer* to me. Moreover, the question clearly states that he wants `cp1252` on the frontend, so the page being *correctly UTF-8* is just some randomness. You can see `<meta>` all over the page, so the code must be really messed up.

Comment: @Raffaele - Never wanted to be a thief, i needed some time to type the answer, so i didn't see your answer. In contrast to your answer i wanted to point out, that one have to set the charset to the **connection object**, not in the database configurations. Because i saw the different meta tags in the example, i assumed, that kimbebot is not against using UTF-8, and the different tags do intervene. If you look at the linked article, you can see, that this is not a spontaneous answer, i had this problem myself, and spent quite some time to write the article.

Comment: @Raffaele - Btw, reading your answer needs some time too. But i like it, so you have my vote...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound so harsh :) The problem is that it took me quite some time to experiment and came up with an aswer. I didn't only state that labels are truncated in the DB, I also gave a reason why. If you read my answer carefully, you'll notice that I mentioned that the problem is the **discrepancy** between the connection declared charset and the PHP string encoding, so you either change one or the other. I got angry because right 10 minutes after my answer came yours, which truly doesn't add anything to mine. Anyway I'm sorry if I hurt you :) peace

Comment: @Raffaele - No damage done, i wanted to help and you wanted to help, and the problem points clearly in this direction. Go on writing such helpful answers, cheerio!